# Are there any other mining clients than Ethminer?

Tags: mining, clients

I mine with ethminer on dwarfpool.

I use this version: 0.9.41-genoil-1.0.7 Beta for Windows. I would like to try another client if its possible. Is there another client than ethminer? I would like to try another one because he crashed a a lot.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the GPU mining section of [Ethereum Homestead documentation - Mining](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html). Your choice will depend on your whether you have an AMD or NVIDIA GPU and your operating system.

You may want to consider moving away from dwarfpool as they control too much hashrate - see [If you are miner, please consider moving away from dwarfpool (44%)](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/48s4b8/if_you_are_miner_please_consider_moving_away_from/). This link also contains a list of other pools and some of these pools provide downloads to slightly different mining clients - you may find one more suitable in this list.

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me understand the relationship between the Ethereum client (e.g. geth, parity) and the Ethereum mining client (e.g. ethminer). My naive guess is that they communicate somehow over JSON-RPC, and the former manages the whole blockchain whereas the mining client just provides it with work to do. But I'm not sure I understand what the value of ethminer is, and why there are two separate elements in the mining stack. How would you explain it?

Comment: Thanks for opening up a new question [How does ethminer interact with the various Etherum clients (e.g. geth, eth, parity) when mining? Does it affect mining efficiency?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3460/how-does-ethminer-interact-with-the-various-etherum-clients-e-g-geth-eth-par) `@William`.

Answer (score 1):

I would checkout [Claymore's](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1433925) dual Ethereum+Decrad miner. Currently only works with windows but he has confirmed a linux build to be release in the next week or two. Hope this helps and will also boost your earnings with dual mining. Note their is a developer fee of 1% and it only currently supports AMD cards.

Comment: Interesting. Is this open sourced?

Comment: Nope it is closed source but Claymore has developed many other successful mining clients.

Comment: I would stay away from closed source programs as there is always a slight chance of compromising your systems, and it is not worth it compromising your whole network/computer for some extra hashrate or convenience. But I'm one paranoid BokkyPooBah.

Comment: And it mines for developer taking 1% or 2% of your uptime: "every hour the miner mines for 36 or 72 seconds for developer" Which causes pool drop, for example nanopool complains that it lost contact with my worker..... So, here is close source example for you :)